# Caching executes DB query anyway

Tags: php, caching, yii

Trying to cache a query:

```
$cache = new CDbCacheDependency( "SELECT * FROM team WHERE team_url = '$url' LIMIT 1" );
$teamModel = Team::model()->cache( 100000, $cache )->findByAttributes( array( "team_url" => $url ) );
```

In the log I see:

```
system.db.CDbCommand
Querying SQL: SELECT * FROM team WHERE team_url = 'someteamname'
LIMIT 1
---
system.caching.CFileCache
Serving "yii:dbquerymysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx:xxx_user:SELECT
* FROM `team` `t` WHERE `t`.`team_url`=:yp0 LIMIT
1:a:1:{s:4:":yp0";s:14:"someteamname";}" from cache
in
```

if the query is cached why is it being executed each time?

EDIT:

I have confirmed that the query is hitting the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line will always show as it is being written to the trace unconditionally. See [CDbCommand:484](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L484).

Comment: right, but I was looking at the queries executed on the server and I did see it execute even though it was supposed to be cached...

Comment: Ah ... wait ... The cache dependency and the to-be-cached query are essentially the same. Is it possible you're seeing the cache dependency being re-evaluated on the db server?

Comment: hmm.. I think you are right... the dependency query will be ran everytime right?

Answer (score 0):

Because it shows the query even if it is pulling the query from cache. That's just the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm whether the query really gets executed by checking the mysql query log.

In mysql console

```
mysql>   SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

mysql> show variables like '%general%';
```

You will get an output like this

```
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                                                       
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| general_log      | ON                                                           
| general_log_file | /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Mac-mini.log 
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Take a terminal tab and enter this command

```
tail -f general_log_file name
```

(Eg:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Mac-mini.log)

Then Refresh the page in your application.Now you can see what are the queries really gets executed in mysql.